# How can I read in csv files with columns as variable names in Python?

Tags: python, csv

This is a Python question. I have a csv file and would like to read that in. The first row in the file are strings and I would like to use them as variable names. The other rows are integers and I would like them to be a vector of the name of the respective variable.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

you need to first extract your first row I suggest to count the characters of first row and use this code to read them

f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
print(f.read(5))#put your desired counted charactor inside f.read(n)

when you successfully read it save it on variable and after saving use regex to split them with respect to ","

import re
txt = "The rain in Spain"
x = re.split("[,]", txt, 1)
print(x)

after that use dictionary methods to attain your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use pandas to read .csv files. Just install pandas using 'pip install pandas'. Then use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Returns a list containing names of the columns
column_names = list(dataframe.columns.values)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I plan to use the function "LinearRegression" from the "sklearn" library. That function doesn't seem to accept dataframes, so having an array ("Numpy") directly would make it a bit easier. What would be the fastest way of getting an array out of a csv file? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but you can simple use "np_array = dataframe.to_numpy()" to convert that data-frame into a numpy array.